# Decomposition of the mean squared error

Tags: mse, calibration, decomposition

In [this blogpost](https://www.unofficialgoogledatascience.com/2021/04/why-model-calibration-matters-and-how.html) given a probabilistic binary classifier, with prediction $\hat{p} \in [0,1]$ and label $Y \in \{0,1\}$, the authors claim the following decomposition of the mean squared error.
$$\mathbb{E}[(\hat{p}-Y)^2] = \mathbb{E}[(\hat{p}-\pi(\hat{p}))^2]-\mathbb{E}[(\pi(\hat{p})-\bar{\pi})^2]+\bar{\pi}(1-\bar{\pi}). $$
Here $\pi(\hat{p})$ denotes the conditional probability $\Pr(Y=1|\hat{p})$, and $\bar{\pi}$ denotes the marginal probability $\Pr(Y=1).$

I think this decomposition is wrong. I let $\hat{p} \sim Beta(2,2)$ and $Y \sim Ber(0.3)$ be independent. The LHS is 0.3 and the RHS is 0.333333.

Am I wrong here? Is the decomposition wrong?

If I am wrong, please let me know how. And if the authors are wrong, I would love to know the correct decomposition of MSE involving the calibration. Thanks.

Comment: see decomposition section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule#Decomposition

Comment: @seanv507 Looking at this entry it seems that all proper scoring rules have the same expected value? Is that right?

Comment: Oh actually the particular values listed are only for Brier score. Ignore my previous comment please.